# PHP using str_replace - Inadvertent Deletion / Using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

Bit of a problem. I'm writing a simple function to get rid of the following symbols: < > [ ] { }. It simply deletes it from a  input.

```
So I have:
$find = array("&lt;", "&gt;", "[", "]", "{", "}"); 
$replace = array("");
$cleanDetails = str_replace($find,$replace,$temporaryDetails);
```

The problem is, that for example, if I write:

> ```
> Oh! This is a <?php sample text ?>
> ```

It will eliminate everything from < up until > included! The result becomes:

> `Oh! This is a`

So (and I don't understand preg_replace any better) I come up with:

```
$cleanDetails = preg_replace("/[\[<{}>\]]*/","",$temporaryDetails);
```

And it won't replace individual <, > {, }, [ or ], but it will delete pairs!
Gah! How can I make either one work?

Comment: Your first code works fine if you add the literal `"<", ">"` https://3v4l.org/BEChV It doesn't remove anything more than you specify.

Comment: Your second code works as well https://3v4l.org/m55Cd you don't need the * in the pattern though.  Not sure why you think these do other than what they show..

Comment: For the `str_replace` you only need pass a single `''` for the replacement value. It does not need to be an array.

Comment: It will not remove PHP from a string, because the PHP is processed before the string is returned to the replacing function.  So that is a bad example/.  If your not seeing `sample text` you probably have some PHP issue such as not echoing it out.

Comment: Works fine for me [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a6d186c42868d9a1aced4c171c44c185f6dfd539) -note- I didn't see any other way to put PHP tags in a string then to use output buffering.  Note that this is not a valid  way `$temporaryDetails = "Oh! This is a <?php echo 'sample text'; ?>";`  as that is just text.

Answer (score 0):

### What is happening?

> It will eliminate everything from < up until > included!

No, it's worse: it won't sanitize anything. You can't see the `<?php ...?>` because PHP tags are not valid in HTML files, so the browser automatically converts it to comments since it doesn't know what else to do with it, look at the page source:

[image]

Have you tried the same with other strings, say `"Oh! This is a <b>sample text </b>"`? I'm sure you'd see it **bold**.

Here's your code in the php shell:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $find = array("&lt;", "&gt;", "[", "]", "{", "}"); 
php > $replace = array("");
php > $temporaryDetails = 'Oh! This is a <?php sample text ?>';
php > $cleanDetails = str_replace($find, $replace, $temporaryDetails);
php > echo $cleanDetails;
Oh! This is a <?php sample text ?>
```

---

### Why is this happening?

Is `str_replace` broken? Nope, it is doing exactly what you told it to do: to replace

- `&lt;`
- `&gt;`
- `[`
- `]`
- `{`
- `}`

with the empty string.

The problem simply is: none of those are there in `"<?php sample text ?>"`, because `"&lt;"` is **not** the same as `"<"`. The first is a four-characters string, the second is a single-character one.

Look at this:

```
php > $temporaryDetails = 'Oh! This is a &lt;?php sample text ?&gt;';
php > $cleanDetails = str_replace($find, $replace, $temporaryDetails);
php > echo $cleanDetails;
Oh! This is a ?php sample text ?
```

---

### A working solution

What you want is probably:

```
$find = array("<", ">", "[", "]", "{", "}");
$replace = "";
```